# PostgreSQL Delete Row where equal to String delimited by comma

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv, sql-delete

I am beginner to SQL, I have some rows that I wish to delete through the use of executing a query.

For example, I have a table:

```
     ID                  │           Type            │ 
─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼
 220                     │ aaa                       │ 
 220                     │ bbb                       │
 220                     │ ccc                       │ 
 220                     │ ddd                       │ 
 220                     │ eee                       │ 
 220                     │ fff                       │
```

And I have a string that is delimited by commas:

`aaa, bbb, fff, ddd`

I wish to delete all rows that are equal to ID of 220 and where Type is equal to a value in the string.

How could I go about this.

Thanks very much

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html, specifically for string_to_array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option splits the string to an array, and then uses `any()`:

```
delete 
from mytable 
where id = 220 and type = any(string_to_array('aaa, bbb, fff, ddd', ', ' ))
```

Comment: If the string really contains white space after the comma, you probably need `regexp_split_to_array(..., '\s*,\s*')`. As written, the second element in that array will be `' bbb'` not `'bbb'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: if commas are consistently followed by a space, wouldn't it work? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=298d74bb087e75b5f3bd010201d45f97

Comment: Interesting. It seems that leading space are indeed removed. Trailing spaces aren't however: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=937f79a090ca3f5791bcd27c7f7c4701

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name; yes, I think because spaces are note consistent in your example. If we had `('aaa , bbb , fff , ddd)'`, then we could use `' , '`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd3a47e651a98d97d50eeeed2cd9617b